# Option to add questions to reading list/subscribe to them?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have some questions I feel like saying **"Me Too!!!"** to and some that are interesting enough so that I would like to keep myself posted on developments like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/552999/how-to-warn-noise-bleep-when-ubuntu-is-about-to-go-into-sleep-mode) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676046/how-can-i-automatically-add-workspaces-only-if-i-need-them).

Would be awesome if I didn't have to try writing a Python script to notify me of changes on the page OR having to bookmark them and manually checking back.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/270345

Comment: You can star a question to mark it as favourite. You'll see them in your profile at the tab "Favourites". If anything changes, the question in the list will get highlighted and a bubble with the number of recently changed favourites will be added to the "Favourites" tab.

Comment: Got it. Thanks both. I should really start reading more and more documentation. Too many downvotes lately. **:P**

Comment: @ByteCommander: Convert to answer, leave comment, upvote, etc...  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Answered, as per your request... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can star a question to mark it as favourite.

You'll see them in your profile at the tab "Favourites". If anything changes, the question in the list will get highlighted and a bubble with the number of recently changed favourites will be added to the "Favourites" tab.

[image: screenshot]

Please also see the detailed article on Stack Exchange Meta at [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/270345)

Comment: Thanks! upvoted!  ;-)